# trying to link address table with companyX

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question related to mysql relationships. Let's say I have 4 table *companya  companyb companyc* and  *companyd*, each containing 3 columns: `name`, `phone`, and `age`. Also I have another table called *address* which I want to link to each companyX with this address table , let’s say if I did `select * from companyX;` the address column should appearnext to each name.

Can this be done with mysql?

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables?

Comment: nothing i done tried many thing but didn't succeed.

Comment: If you only have those three columns in the company<x> tables, you can't link to address effectively. You would need a company ID / key of some sort, and then you'd use that key in your address table. You might need to rethink your tables.

Comment: can you give me example please im ready to add company id to my table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the company tables have the exact same structure why don't you use only a single table to store the information? You may want to read about [database normalization](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30646).

Secondly you could create a relation table named something like 'companiesAddresses' and store fields such as "CompanyID" and "AddressID" in it (you obviously would have to create a primary key column in your companyX's table and do the same in the 'addresses' table so then you could use the INNER JOIN clause to get the information you want such as `SELECT companyX.companyName, addresses.Address FROM companyX INNER JOIN companiesAddresses ON companyX.CompanyID = companiesAddresses.CompanyID INNER JOIN addresses ON companiesAddresses.AddressID = addresses.AddressID`.

I hope I understood what you want correctly.

Comment: no not exactly what i want, i just need to do simply query select * from companyX; and show address table there.